# What is the bottleneck of Android app debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, device

I know there are many discussions about the emulator which is so slow that is essentially unusable for routine debugging tasks.   I am talking about debugging with physical devices.  My app runs about an order of magnitude slower in debug mode than in non-debug mode.  I mean “an order of magnitude” literally.  I can think of three possible candidates for the bottleneck:

1. Computer.
2. Android device.
3. Eclipse.

Checking my computer during debugging shows its quad-core CPU and 8 GB memory on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit has plenty of room left. The devices I use are Samsung Admire running Gingerbread, Airpad X running ICS (a generic tablet).  My Eclipse is Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857.
Could any experts, especially those who have successfully boosted Android app debugging performance offer some tips

Comment: "I know there are many discussions about the emulator which is so slow that is essentially unusable for routine debugging tasks" -- try the x86 images available for 2.3.3 and 4.0.3.

Comment: I have to agree to @CommonsWare - since Intel released the Gingerbread and ICS images Android debugging in the emulator got so much better.

Comment: it doesn't always work as fast as they claim . for me , even though i have the specs needed , it didn't show any improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It is interesting that the X86 Image for Android 2.3.3 is noticeably much faster (2 - 3x) than the image for Android 4.0.1. I run them side by side to watch their performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not a solution , but a few tips that might make the problem a little less , well, problematic :

1. try to reduce the number of logs written at runtime.
2. you can run the app normally , and then debug it at runtime . simply choose the process via eclipse , and choose the bug-icon in the ddms view (not the one next to the launch-icon) .
3. same as #2 , but inside the code : use "[waitForDebugger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger%28%29)" when you see fit.
4. try to reduce the number of expressions that need to be evaluated in the debug mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent tips. It seems Eclipse is the bottleneck. One of the reasons that I asked the question is I was debating whether I should get a faster mobile device for the sake boosting the debugging performance. It looks like that would be a waste of money. It is slow even LogCat shows very few messages and no expressions need to be evaluated.

Comment: try to update ADT&SDK (even to the preview version , which is 20 preview 3) , update eclipse (current is  3.7.0) , update java , and try to increase the memory limit that is enforced on eclipse .